# Scale or Scaling of a vertical axis?

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct word to describe the "size" of the vertical axis of a graph?

Suppose one graph's axis goes from 0 to 10 with tick size 1 and the other one from 0 to 100 with tick size 10.
Then the two graphs have different ... (scales or scalings?) of the vertical axis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right word is **scale** when one speaks about the settings. **scaling** refers to a result of changing the dimensions of an object within a scale.